# Can Jinja2 block tags use optional arguments?

Tags: python, jinja2

Can I write a Jinaj2 block tag that may or may not take a single argument?

For example, both of these calls would be valid:

```
{% some_tag "one arg" %}
```

and

```
{% some_tag %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you try to accomplish, but you can use a default:

```
{% ....... |default('no_argument') %}
```